# Get contentpresenter location (size and offset from owner)

Tags: c#, wpf, adorner

I need a way to dynamically retrieve (not knowing what type of frameworkElement), the content/items presenter size and offset from the owner's edges in any form.

I need to create an adorner that covers the content area of a control.

Comment: I tried looking in visual tree helper, but content bounds doesn't mean contentPresenter, and it's returning empty anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the VisualTreeHelper to identify the ContentPresenter/ItemPresenter from the object if it exists.

Use the following code to get an offset:

```
presenter.TransformToVisual(control).Transform(new Point(0,0));
```

Call on presenter whatever desired properties that will give you size (Actual[Height/Width], etc.)